# Update Trigger Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 with a table named dbo.ClientRecords.  In this table I have a DateOfBirth field set as DATETIME and an Age field set as Nvarchar(40) at the moment.  I know that this needs to be changed to int and I will do this.

I have the following query that essentially does a calculation based on the DateOfBirth field and the current date to work out the Age of the person.  This works as I require it to.

```
SELECT id, DateOfBirth,
    GETDATE() As [Today], 
    DATEDIFF (YY,DateOfBirth,GETDATE()) -
    CASE
        WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DateOfBirth,GETDATE()),DateOfBirth)
        > GETDATE() THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS [Age]
FROM dbo.ClientRecords
```

I am following the below website to create an update trigger as I need this update the age field once the insert statement for the web form has been submitted.

[Tutorial about Triggers](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-with-example.aspx)

This is my trigger that im trying to create, but I just cant seem to get this working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Age_INSERT]
       ON [dbo].[ClientRecords]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @id DATETIME
       DECLARE @Age Varchar(40)

        SELECT id,DateOfBirth,
        GETDATE() As [Today], 
        DATEDIFF (YY,DateOfBirth,GETDATE()) -
        CASE
            WHEN DATEADD(YY,DATEDIFF(YY,DateOfBirth,GETDATE()),DateOfBirth)
            > GETDATE() THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS [Age]
        FROM dbo.ClientRecords

       INSERT INTO ClientRecords
       VALUES(@id, @Age)
END
```

The error message that I get is the following.

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Age_INSERT, Line 21
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

I'm failing as im not to sure what I need to set as a variable.  I thought that I would need the id from the ClientRecords table and the Age field.

Comment: Can you share clientrecords schema,why you need a trigger..won't constraint work..if your trying to calculate only age

Comment: Do you actually mean to create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that performs an `UPDATE`?

Comment: Agree with @mustaccio. You need an `AFTER INSERT` trigger. Also, you should be selecting from the `inserted` table to calculate the age. Then Update the record. You may want to consider a calculated column rather than a trigger for the age.

Comment: Why bother storing somebody's age in your table. As soon as you store it the data is stale. You would have to run an update across the entire table every day to make sure your data is current. I would just calculate age on the fly when you need it. And in your trigger I think you want to be doing an update, not an insert.

Comment: Triggers fire once per _statement_, not per _row_, so if an `UPDATE` affects 42 rows your trigger will need to deal with that. (Hence the `inserted` and `deleted` tables.) And, as previously noted, you need a trigger on `GETDATE` since you're chasing a moving target.

Comment: Hi folks,  many thanks for your suggestions, they have been much help. @WEI_DBA, I have now created a 'Computed Field' for the 'Age' field and not used the Trigger.   I have simply replaced the column with the following code:  [Age]  AS (datediff(YY,[DateOfBirth],getdate())).   This calculates the age but it isn't correct.  E.G a birthday of 23/09/1980 should pull back a value of 36, but pulls back 37.  I have tried to do a couple of things with the case statement I submitted earlier in the post but am unsure how to do this with a computed column?

Comment: Morning all,  I have managed to complete this using a function and then adding this function to the computed column by field.